# Continuous function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, compactness

Let $1 \leq m \leq n$, $g$ and $h$ continuous function of compact support, $g: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ and $h:\mathbb R^{n-m} \to \mathbb R$.

We define $g \star h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$ g \star h(x_1, \ldots , x_n) = g(x_1, \ldots, x_m)h(x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n) $$

Prove that $g \star h$ is continuous of compact support and that $\int g \circ h = (\int g)(\int h)$

Any ideas? I'm trying to prove that it's continuous using the definition, but I can't get anywhere useful.
I know how to do the last part (integrals) I just need to see that it is a continuous function and that its support is compact.

Comment: If $x$ is close to $a$ then each $x_i-a_i$ is small so that $g\star h(x)$ is close to $g\star h(a)$. For the integral it is quite obvious from $\int_{R^n} f(x)d^nx= \int_{R^m}\int_{R^{n-m}} f(y,z)d^myd^{n-m}z$. For the compact support : if $\|x\|$ is large then one of the $|x_i|$ is large so that one of $g,h$ vanishes

Answer (score 2):

Note the projections $\pi_1 : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $\pi_2 : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n-m}$ defined by
$$ \pi_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_m), \quad \text{and} \quad 
\pi_2(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n)$$
are continuous. Then $g \star h = (g \circ \pi_1) (h \circ \pi_2)$ is continuous as compositions and products of continuous functions. If the support of $g$ and $h$ are contained in the compact sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ resepectively then it shouldn't be difficult to show the support of $g \star h$ is contained in $K_1 \times K_2$ which will still be compact.

Comment: By K1xK2 do you mean {(a, b) | a∈K1, b∈K2}??

Comment: I mean $K_1 \times K_2$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. If we're being that technical, $K_1 \times K_2$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^{n - m}$ is homeomorphic to $K_1 \times K_2$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ so for showing compactness are the same.